# How to open product detail when user click on product image?

Tags: commerce

I am new in Drupal and I am working on one commerce website using drupal commerce module.

The problem is arise in my website is-->

I am used views for display products with product image,title, price etc fields.

But I want to know that when user click on product image the new page will open and in that page display 3 related images of that product with detail information.

I want to give link for product image to open that clicked image product with detail.

Please help me to solved this problem...!

Answer (score 0):

In view add "nid" fields before image field and make exclude from display.

Click on image field.
Go to "Rewrite Results" section.Check "output this field as link" .In the "link path" put the 'nid'. It will take you the details page of product.
...[image]

You can also create tpl file for product content type details page.
Enjoy

Comment: Thanks Sir, But in view I was selected commerce products, hence there was no any field like "nid"?

Comment: Ok go to "advanced" section in view and click on "Relationships".Check here by adding some relation related to content.Then check the field available like nid. Else instated of searching nid do the same thing using title.Means in link path put [title] with site url.

Comment: Yaa, It's working but it show's popup window for admin to enter value.

Comment: I am not getting you.Which one works for you.It will better if you go for details.

Comment: I give link path to image like [title] and when I click on product image it shows me popup window, to edit product details.

Comment: it will be better put screen shot of both product details page and view page.